# Are rigor rigs always superior to flare rigs?

Tags: eve-online

Until recently I thought that the optimal rig configuration for a cruise missile PvE ship like a Raven is 2x Rigor and 1x Flare. This seemed pretty sensible as almost everything is affected by a stacking penalty which gets rather severe from the third stacking effect on.

But very recently I was told that three Rigor rigs are always superior or equal to 2x Rigor and 1x Flare rigs, and that you only fit the second version if you don't have enough calibration for three rigor rigs.

Is there some hard evidence on that? I would have expected the stacking penalty to put the configuration with three identical rigs at a significant disadvantage.

Answer (score 2):

As far as on-paper DPS, 3x Rigor rigs are always superior to 2x Rigor and 1x Flare. As to in-game dps, I see extremely little difference between the two setups on sisi lobbing torps or cruise at BC/cruisers. If this will make a difference, it will be 10 DPS or less.  ( though, if you're really insane, use 2x Rigor T2 and 1x Flare T2 for best results)